# Checkboxlist display ID and not Text

Tags: c#, linq, data-binding, checkboxlist

I'm creating a checkboxlist dynamically which is populated through linq. The list of checkboxes does get created, but instead of displaying the value(text) which should be name + surname it is displaying the ID's for the users.

This is what I've done:

```
    private void CreateUsersList()
    {
        chkUsers.Items.Clear();

        var query = (from u in context.SkillAssestUsers
                     select new
                        {
                            u.ID,
                            u.Name,
                            u.Surname
                        }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

        chkUsers.AutoPostBack = false;
        chkUsers.CellPadding = 5;
        chkUsers.CellSpacing = 5;
        chkUsers.RepeatColumns = 4;
        chkUsers.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
        chkUsers.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Table;
        chkUsers.TextAlign = TextAlign.Right;
        chkUsers.CssClass = "CheckBoxList";

        if (query != null)
        {
            foreach (var result in query)
            {
                string fullName = result.Name + " " + result.Surname;
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.ID = result.ID.ToString();
                cb.Text = result.Name + " " + result.Surname;
                cb.AutoPostBack = false;
                cb.CssClass = "CheckBox";

                chkUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem(result.ID.ToString(), result.Name + " " + result.Surname));
                chkUsers.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how the data comes through when I run the project:

[image]

So instead of the ID's I want to display the Name and Surname, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong...

Can somebody please point me in the right direction? Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the constructor of a ListItem is:

```
public ListItem(
    string text,
    string value
)
```

So change this line:

```
chkUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem(result.ID.ToString(), 
                   result.Name + " " + result.Surname));
```

to this:

```
chkUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem(result.Name + " " + result.Surname,
                       result.ID.ToString()));
```

Reference:

1. [ListItem Constructor (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f7h2h8h(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [ListItem Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem(v=vs.110).aspx)